# Aura component with google map

Tags: map, aura, component

I'm trying to create an aura component with an embedded google map (the new lightning: map thing) that would show all of our accounts on the map.

I have two problems:

The height of the component is determined by the marker list on the right. So if i have 300 accounts then the height of the component is ridiculously long and the height of the map doesnt follow - so the map is somewhere in the middle and extremely small compared to the list. Is it possible to get rid of the marker list completely or limit its size (and then make the overflow scrollable) ?

Second problem is that with thousands of accounts the component is extremely slow - it might take minutes to load. And it seems like only a small percentage of the accounts actually show up on the map.

I'm using the following javascript:

```
({
    onInit: function( component, event, helper ) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            var xu = data.getReturnValue();
            var mapMarkers = [];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < xu.length; i++) { 
                var marker = {
                    'location': {
                        'Street': xu[i].BillingStreet,
                        'City': xu[i].BillingCity,
                        'PostalCode': xu[i].BillingPostalCode
                    },
                    'icon': 'standard:location'
                };

                mapMarkers.push( marker );
            }
            component.set( 'v.mapMarkers', mapMarkers );
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Any comments on either of these issues would be most welcome.